# Laravel 8 and postgresql

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8 and postgreSql. How can I use inheritance in migration?
There are some packages like [this](https://github.com/rishi-ramawat/laravel-postgresql-inherit) but they are for laravel 5+.

Comment: Your question is not clear, It is suggested that you take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @bhucho I edited it, I hope that it was clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified child_tbl's migration file at this way:

1. adding "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;"
2. adding 'DB::statement("alter table child_tbl inherit parent_tbl");' in "up" function, after "Schema::create" statement.